ListItem delta queries issue from Last 14th June
We are experiencing issues with some listItems delta queries to MS Graph since last Friday, June 14th.
Before that date, this request was working fine:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/items/delta?$select=id,contentType,sharepointIds&$expand=fields($select=Id,DocIcon)&$filter=startsWith(contentType/id,'{contentTypeId}')

As mentioned in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http, the response was returning a 'deltaLink' property with a '$token' that could be used to make an additional request to get changes since the time we had that token, adding $filters, $selects, or whatever we preferred.
"@odata.deltaLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/contoso.sharepoint.com,2C712604-1370-44E7-A1F5-426573FDA80A,2D2244C3-251A-49EA-93A8-39E1C3A060FE/lists/22e03ef3-6ef4-424d-a1d3-92a337807c30/items/delta?**token=1230919asd190410jlka**"

Now, it seems that this has changed.

The response URL now includes a $deltaToken property, but we must use that exact URL to get the changed values, without adding any additional filters or select parameters. Previously we had to get that $token from the response and add it into the request as an extra parameter $token, with the rest of filters, selects...
"@odata.deltaLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/items/microsoft.graph.delta()?$**deltatoken**=gskwApixxxv_HsD9QmnbWSJynW5FUrwtAh1NmFlabefaefaefaf-DuDbYev2cEsqY8W1qLi4OAxuu3tlgmJ2cGfWDM5QoeVvLqK7Pl9tBNA-HbADIOJW-rxQIf-os4jYYXFdbnsjYZi4GjbVLhfXeU0aaNxPDNFgzrI-iSjybL-CxfSaUFBZAyzdCRCcnLjiT2Ut3Hem2kPN2NfKiQ_SlOPKSYQuW6ub1IHxxveVGNGbaFE_Ts29xrt6CyN6U0RqG3cuuNpBGociFcjVZ-paU-E6Smk7m8jsbv61vY2qZTl9oj2pttT_qxfejtZUXkBQENctqlhWyMlRNuHewM26T3oLV3cGdOc63UJ1Me9J65aaoKnImV2yVWXtn..."

Additionally, we have noticed other changes. For instance, even if we specify to obtain the driveItemId, it is being ignored, which was
working fine a few days ago (both in beta and the stable version).
&$expand=driveItem($select=id)

The following filter is now failing, although it was working correctly in Beta:
and (fields/DocIcon eq 'txt' or fields/DocIcon eq 'md' or
fields/DocIcon eq 'json' or fields/DocIcon eq 'docx' or fields/DocIcon
eq 'pdf' or fields/DocIcon eq 'xlsx' or fields/DocIcon eq 'pptx')

This also happened more or less in April and finally was reverted some days after.
Any idea about how it should work now? Is this a temporary issue?
